# Can I create a one-item array in Logstash?

Tags: logstash

I have a use case where a String field sometimes contains one value and sometime contains multiple values. This is causing a problem downstream because our avro schema specifies type "Array" on this field but sometime receives a "String" type.

I have no way to change the downstream logic and I would rather like to avoid converting my Arrays to concatenated Strings as a workaround. Is there a way to create a one-item Array in Logstash?

**Research**

There is a [convert filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) in Logstash but it doesn't explicitly allow for conversion to String Arrays and the following does not work:

```
mutate {
    convert => {"FieldName" => "[string]"}
}
```

I have also tried explicitly recreating the field as an Array with no luck.

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "[FieldName_temp]" => "%{FieldName}" }
    remove_field => { "FieldName" }
}

mutate {
    rename => { "[FieldName_temp]" => "[FieldName]" }
}
```

Is what I'm attempting even possible in Logstash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common filter option add_field will convert a string to an array if the field already exists, or append an entry to an array, then you can remove the last entry in the array.

```
mutate { add_field => { "foo" => 2 } }
mutate { remove_field => [ "[foo][-1]" ] }
```

You could also do it using a ruby filter, but I think this is harder to understand:

```
ruby { code => 'event.set("foo", [ event.get("foo") ].flatten)' }
```

Comment: Not wholly necessary, but do you know which of these two solutions is more efficient?

Comment: I would guess the ruby filter is more efficient, but both are so cheap that I would not use that to decide between them.